# Is there any other date of mahabharata except 3102bce in the astronomical terms?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, krishna, history, birth

There is a date given to mahabharata by calculating krishna's birth.which is 3102 bce.
Is there any other dates can be found
Beside this in the astronomical terms?

Comment: By what means do you want a date? This site only accepts dates from, or calculable from, sacred texts. Without an edit, your question risks being closed on the assumption that you want an academically accurate (as accurate as possible) answer. This site is not pro-scholarship, so if that's what you want you should seek elsewhere.